# convert string to hex in lua?

Tags: string, sockets, lua, hex, arrays

I am going to send a byte array through socket.But I used to work in c/c++ and be new to lua.
Now i have a problem,here is my question.

i want to send a bytearray.It should contain mac_address,string_length,string.

For detail:

mac_address:6 bytes
length of string: 1 byte
string:several bytes

(1)first question
Now,I have a string of mac_address like“01：2f:c2:5e:b6:a3”,how can I convert it into a 6 byte hex array?

(2)second
how to define an unsigned number and store it to byte?for example,sting_length is 33,how can i store it as 0x21 into a byte?

(3)last
how to combine mac_address(6bits),string_length(1bit),data_string(for example,100bytes) into a byte array,and successfully send it out through luasocket.

that's all.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.char` to get a symbol representation of a number, which will allow you to pack numbers into bytes. Something like this should work:

```
local function packet(address, str)
  return address:gsub("(%x+):?",function(s) return string.char(tonumber(s, 16)) end)
  .. string.char(#str)
  .. str
end

print(packet("10:2f:c2:5e:b6:a3", "abc") == "\16/\194^\182\163\3abc")
```

`gsub` takes every group in the address, `tonumber(s, 16)` converts the hex number into a decimal and `string.char` converts it into a character (one-byte) representation. It's all then packed together into one string that can be sent. This is the Lua representation of the resulting string: `"\16/\194^\182\163\3abc"`.

Comment: You should use `%x` instead of `%w`

Answer (score 0):

```
function hexbyte(a,b)
b1=string.byte(a)
b2=string.byte(b)
result = 0 
  if (b1 >= string.byte('A')) then
     result = 16*result + b1 - string.byte('A') +10
           else
     result = 16*result + b1 - string.byte('0')
  end

  if (b2 >= string.byte('A')) then
     result = 16*result  + b2 - string.byte('A') +10
  else
     result = 16* result + b2 - string.byte('0')
 end
 return string.format('%02X', (result))
 end
```

Comment: It takes two charters and e.g 'C' & '3' and returns the hex C3. 
Also if you need the decimal of 0xC3 which 195 then you can simply do 
return result

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
local function PrintHex(data)
    for i = 1, #data do
        char = string.sub(data, i, i)
        io.write(string.format("%02x", string.byte(char)) .. " ")
    end
end
```