# Lua: Hexadecimal Word to Binary Conversion

Tags: lua, hex, byte, bit, data-conversion

I'm attempting to create a Lua program to monitor periodic status pings of a slave device.  The slave device sends its status in 16-bit hexadecimal words, which I need to convert to a binary string since each bit pertains to a property of the device.  I can receive the input string, and I have a table containing 16 keys for each parameter.  But I am having a difficult time understanding how to convert the hexadecimal word into a string of 16-bits so I can monitor it.

Here is a basic function of what I'm starting to work on.

```
function slave_Status(IP,Port,Name)
    status = path:read(IP,Port)
    sTable = {}
    if status then
        sTable.ready=bit32.rshift(status:byte(1), 0)
        sTable.paused=bit32.rshift(status:byte(1), 1)
        sTable.emergency=bit32.rshift(status:byte(1), 2)
        sTable.started=bit32.rshift(status:byte(1), 3)
        sTable.busy=bit32.rshift(status:byte(1), 4)
        sTable.reserved1=bit32.rshift(status:byte(1), 5)
        sTable.reserved2=bit32.rshift(status:byte(1), 6)
        sTable.reserved3=bit32.rshift(status:byte(1), 7)
        sTable.reserved4=bit32.rshift(status:byte(2), 0)
        sTable.delay1=bit32.rshift(status:byte(2), 1)
        sTable.delay2=bit32.rshift(status:byte(2), 2)
        sTable.armoff=bit32.rshift(status:byte(2), 3)
        sTable.shieldoff=bit32.rshift(status:byte(2), 4)
        sTable.diskerror=bit32.rshift(status:byte(2), 5)
        sTable.conoff=bit32.rshift(status:byte(2), 6)
        sTable.envoff=bit32.rshift(status:byte(2), 7)
    end
end
```

I hope this approach is understandable?  I'd like to receive the Hex strings, for example `0x18C2` and turn that to `0001 1000 1100 0010`, shifting the right-most bit to the right and placing that into the proper key.  Then later in the function I would monitor if that bit had changed for the better or worse.

If I run a similar function in Terminator in Linux, and print out the pairs I get the following return:

```
49
24
12
6
3
1
0
0
56
28
14
7
3
1
0
0
```

This is where I am not understanding how to take each value and set it to bits

I'm pretty new to this so I do not doubt that there is an easier way to do this.  If I need to explain further I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd approach this in a different fashion than the one suggested by Paul.

First, create a table storing the properties of devices:

```
local tProperty = {
    "ready",
    "paused",
    "emergency",
    "started",
    "busy",
    "reserved1",
    "reserved2",
    "reserved3",
    "reserved4",
    "delay1",
    "delay2",
    "armoff",
    "shieldoff",
    "diskerror",
    "conoff",
    "envoff",
}
```

Then, since your device sends the data as `0xYYYY`, you can call `tonumber` directly (if not a string). Use a function to store each bit in a table:

```
function BitConvert( sInput )
    local tReturn, iNum = {}, tonumber( sInput ) -- optionally pass 16 as second argument to tonumber
    while iNum > 0 do
        table.insert( tReturn, 1, iNum % 2 )
        iNum = math.floor( iNum / 2 )
    end
    for i = #tProperty - #tReturn, 1, -1 do
        table.insert( tReturn, 1, 0 )
    end
    return tReturn
end
```

And then, map both the tables together:

```
function Map( tKeys, tValues )
    local tReturn = {}
    for i = 1, #tKeys do
        tReturn[ tKeys[i] ] = tValues[i]
    end
    return tReturn
end
```

In the end, you would have:

```
function slave_Status( IP, Port, Name )
    local status = path:read( IP, Port )
    local sTable = Map( tProperty, BitConvert(status) )
end
```

Comment: I separated your code and ran it in Terminator to better understand the method behind your madness.  I ran only the `BitConvert(sInput)` and printed the key,value terms of `tReturn{}`.  It does break it into binary which is great.  But when it distributes the binary terms it seems to be in reverse.  I like your approach because it explicitly shows me how you would approach this conversion methodically.  But I need to switch the order it seems.  I will see about flipping the order.  Otherwise, I love your approach hjpotter92!  Thank you.

Comment: @Pwrcdr87 If the order is reversed; change all `table.insert( tReturn, 1, val )` to `table.insert( tReturn, val )`

Comment: changed `table.insert(tReturn, 1, iNum%2)` to `table.insert(tReturn,iNum%2)` and `table.insert( tReturn, 1, 0 )` to `table.insert( tReturn, 0 )`.  The order is flipped as you stated!  I know I am new but I should have noticed that each entry was being placed into the first position of each list!  Thank you very much hjpotter!  Great answer!

Answer (score 3):

`tonumber(s, 16)` will convert hex representation to decimal and `string.char` will return a symbol/byte representation of a number. Check this [recent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29419947/1442917) for an example of how they can be used; the solution in the answer may work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I looked over the linked and understand why you provided it.  But I like hjpotter's approach a bit more.  Sorry but thank you for your input!